# How is pipe involved in ssh?

Tags: ssh, pipe

My internet connection was lost When I ssh to a remote machine over the internet.
It says

```
$ Write failed: Broken pipe
```

How is pipe involved in ssh?

Does ssh implement communication between the two machines based on pipe?

Answer (score 2):

From [write(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write),

> ### Errors
>
> ⋮
>
> **EPIPE**
>
>   *fd*
>   is connected to a pipe or socket whose reading end is closed. 
>     When this happens the writing process
>     will also receive a
>   **SIGPIPE**
>   signal.  …

In other words, pipes and sockets, while not the same thing,
are similar enough that Unix uses the same mechanism
to inform a writing process that
there is no longer any place for the data to go.

Answer (score 0):

SSH sets up a "pipe" between the two servers for the communication channel. It broke, so the SSH session collapsed.

Comment: thanks. there are a local computer and a remote computer. What are "the two servers"?

Comment: The first server is the local computer, the second server is the remote computer.

Comment: Really it's a client/server relationship.  I think the misunderstanding is the term "pipe", which in this context is not referring to `pipe(2)` but rather a more general term describing a two-way communication channel.